# Quadratic extensions of local fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For a given prime number $p$, for which quadratic extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is it true that for all places $w$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ such that $w|v$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})_w$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_v$?

I'm trying to use the following theorem from Janusz's "Algebraic Number Fields": Let $L=K(\theta)$ be an extension field of $K$ (where $L$ and $K$ are number fields) and let $f(x)$ be the minimum polynomial of $\theta$ over $K$. Let $K_p$ be the completion of $K$ at a prime $p$ and let $f(x)=\Pi_{i=1}^g f_i(x)$ be the factorization of $f$ over $K_p$. Then the primes of $L$ that extend $p$ correspond one-to-one with the factors $f_i(x)$ of $f(x)$. If $p_i$ corresponds to $f_i(x)$, then the completions $L_i$ of $L$ at $p_i$ satisfies

$L_i \cong K_p/(f_i(x))$.

In the context of my question, $f(x)=x^2-d$. I want the $L_i$ to be quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. So I need $d$ so that $x^2-d$ factors into exactly quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

The theorem which you refer to in Janusz's book concerns a general finite extension $L/K$ of number fields of degree $n$. An additional information is that, for a given place $v$ of $K$, for all places $w_i$ of $L$ over $v$, you have the relation $n = \sum e_i f_i$, where $e_i$  (resp. $f_i$) is the ramification (resp. inertia) index. If moreover the extension $L/K$ is Galois, all the $e_i$'s are the same, as well as all the $f_i$'s, and $n=ref$, where $r$ is the number of places $w$ above $v$.

In the particular case of a quadratic field $L=\mathbf Q(\sqrt d)$, $r=1$ or $2$, and the local field $L_w$ is a quadratic extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ iff $r=1$. The *totally decomposed* case ($r=2$) occurs iff $p=2$ and $d\equiv 1$ mod $8$, or $p$ is odd and $(\frac dp) = 1$.

Comment: Can't you say something like $(1+p a)^{1/2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1/2 \choose k} p^k a^k$ converges in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ iff $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ so that $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ has a square root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ iff $d = a^2 (1+p b)$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Of course yes, but if $p$ is odd, the expression obtained for $d$ using the series summation shows that $d$ is a square in $\mathbf Q_p$, which amounts to $(\frac dp) =1$ by Hensel's lemma. The point is that it's easier to work in the residue field.

Comment: I see, Hensel lemma is more general and shows directly that $(\frac{d}{p}) = 1 \implies \sqrt{d} \in \mathbb{Q}_p$. Also I would define the p-adic norm on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ to avoid talking of places and $e_i,f_i$.